# Pandas split name column into last and first name ignore middle name python

Tags: python, pandas

Still learning pandas so please explain like I'm a newbie. :)
My pandas 10,000 row x 5 column data frame contains names like so,

```py
name_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sanchez, Rick U D','Smith, Jerry C','Smith, Beth Space', 'Smith I, Morty', 'Smith, Summer']})
```

```
     name
0    Sanchez, Rick U D
1    Smith, Jerry C
2    Smith, Beth Space
3    Smith I, Morty
4    Smith, Summer
```

The requirements are,

- Split the `name` into two columns `first_name` and `last_name`
- If there's a middle name, it's dropped from the df. Only have first and last names.
- Commas are removed
- Last names with ending like "Jr, I, II, III, etc." are removed

The desired output is,

```
     last_name  first_name
0    Sanchez    Rick
1    Smith      Jerry
2    Smith      Beth
3    Smith      Morty
4    Smith      Summer
```

What I have so far is below. I'm able to split the column `name` into two separate columns but not sure how to remove the middle name from `first_name` or the commas in `last name`.

```
import pandas as pd
name_df[['last_name','first_name']] = name_df['name'].loc[name_df['name'].str.split().str.len() == 2].str.split(expand=True)
name_df['last_name'].str.replace(',','')
```

Current output:

```
     last_name  first_name
0    NaN        NaN
1    NaN        NaN
2    NaN        NaN
3    NaN        NaN
4    Smith,     Summer
```

Comment: People don't normally call themselves `James Smith I` (unless they're a very forward looking monarch or something). You ought to make sure Smith I isn't truncating something meaningful, say, a full last name "Smith Ismay". It also isn't implausible that someone has two-word given name.

Comment: It's a number like "Charles Window the 3rd". In the dataset,  the name is written like "Window III, Charles".
Fair point though to validate everything. It's quite messy of a dataset.

Comment: Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split()` 2 times:

```
out=name_df['name'].str.split(', ',expand=True)
out[1]=out[1].str.split(' ',1).str[0]
out[0]=out[0].str.split(' ').str[0]
out.columns=['last_name','first_name']
```

Output of `out`:

```
  last_name     first_name
0   Sanchez     Rick
1   Smith       Jerry
2   Smith       Beth
3   Smith       Morty
4   Smith       Summer
```

Comment: How about `Lloyd George, David` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Lloyd_George ? This code would truncate The Earl Lloyd-George's surname to Lloyd. Or perhaps a less historically remote example, `Bonham Carter, Helena`?

Comment: @ifly6 sir op wants to remove middle name as well so it will work **:)**

Comment: David Lloyd George has a given name `David` and surname `Lloyd George`. Splitting on spaces would misinterpret the first part of his surname as the actual surname and `George` as a middle name. The exact same issue occurs with `Bonham Carter, Helena`: your code would render her name as `Helena Bonham`, truncating `Carter`.